# Occurences of a value, based on corresponding value across columns

Tags: google-sheets, count, conditional-statements

I currently have a table in a layout similar to this:

```
Quality | Fruit1 | Fruit2 | Fruit3
----------------------------------
Sweet   | Apple  | Orange | Pear
Firm    | Pear   | Apple  | Watermelon
Sweet   | Orange | Pear   | Melon
Soft    | Banana | Orange | Strawberry
Firm    | Apple  | Melon  | Pear
Sweet   | Melon  | Pear   | Watermelon
```

(The actual table has many more rows, "qualities" and "fruits", though still only three "Fruit#" columns and the one "Quality" column.)

And am trying to create another table, such that it records (for the above example) the number of occurrences for each fruit per quality:

```
           |  Firm  |  Soft  | Sweet
--------------------------------------
Apple      | 2      | 0      | 1
Banana     | 0      | 1      | 0
Melon      | 1      | 0      | 2
Orange     | 0      | 1      | 2
Pear       | 2      | 0      | 3
Strawberry | 0      | 1      | 0
Watermelon | 1      | 0      | 1
```

(The qualities and fruits are deliberately sorted in this table.)

I've tried a number of combinations with VLookup, Match, Index and Countif/s, and I feel like I'm missing something blatantly obvious as nothing has worked as yet.

My thought process for the formula would be something like (in the case of counting `Apple` occurrences in `Firm` rows):

- Check `Quality` for `Firm`
- Check rows with `Firm` for `Apple`
- If an `Apple` is found, add `1` to the count of `Firm:Apple` in the output table.

I would also prefer to avoid functions if possible, though I am unaware if this is even possible with the current layouts.

Comment: It looks like that example utilises functions, which I'd honestly prefer to avoid unless totally necessary. I was thinking of some sort of formula which would check for e.g. `Firm` in `Quality`, then check along the corresponding row/s for e.g. `Apple`, and add 1 to the count for `Firm:Apple` in the output table every time `Apple` is found in a `Firm` row. (I should probably note this in the question, actually.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With row and column labels set up as required for the output and assuming `Quality` is in A1, and `Firm` for the output in G1 then (using functions!) please try:

```
=countifs($B:$B,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)+countifs($C:$C,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)+countifs($D:$D,$F2,$A:$A,G$1)
```

in G2 copied across and down to suit.

Comment: See what I mean by 'blatantly obvious'? Thanks! I came across a solution in the form of summing three`countif(filter(...)...)`, however it's fairly clear your answer is probably a bit more suitable!